# Is it necessary to create a TYPE to pass an array as a parameter to a query in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I noticed in Postgres logs that a certain query runs in bursts, i.e. few hundred times within a short period of time.
I suspect that the application code runs this query in a loop.

I want to recommend the application developers to re-write that piece of code and pass an array (a table) into the query and get the whole result set at once instead of row-by-row.
I have not seen the application code myself. I don't even know what language it is in.

This is the query that I see in the logs:

```
select * 
from 
    "jobs" 
where 
    "location" = $1 
    and "installDate" = $2 
    and "groupId" = $3 
    and "method" = $4

parameters: $1 = 'XYZ', $2 = '2022-03-28', $3 = '3302', $4 = 'ASDF'
```

Logs have hundreds of these calls with very close timestamps.

Instead of passing individual values as parameters and getting one or few rows back for each call I want to pass the whole table of parameters, like this:

```
'XYZ', '2022-03-28', '3302', 'ASDF'
'QWE', '2022-03-28', '3305', 'KJGH'
'RTY', '2022-03-28', '3307', 'UTYH'
'YUI', '2022-03-28', '3301', 'ERYT'
'POI', '2022-03-28', '3399', 'NMBV'
.....
```

In MS SQL Server I'd use a table-valued parameter. In Postgres, I guess, I should use an array, because as far as I know Postgres doesn't have table parameters.

I tried the following and it worked in pgAdmin:

At first I created a type

```
CREATE TYPE test_jobs_filter 
AS 
("location" text
, "installDate" date
, "groupId" text
, "method" character varying(50));
```

Then I used it like this:

```
PREPARE test_q_after (test_jobs_filter[]) AS
SELECT "jobs".*
FROM
    "jobs"
    INNER JOIN unnest($1::test_jobs_filter[]) AS T
        ON T."location" = "jobs"."location"
        AND T."installDate" = "jobs"."installDate"
        AND T."groupId" = "jobs"."groupId"
        AND T."method" = "jobs"."method"
;

EXECUTE test_q_after(
array
[
 ('XYZ', '2022-03-28', '3302', 'ASDF')
,('QWE', '2022-03-28', '3305', 'KJGH')

...

,('RTY', '2022-03-28', '3302', 'UTYH')
]::test_jobs_filter[]
);

DEALLOCATE test_q_after;
```

1. It this the correct / preferred / recommended way to pass a table as a parameter to the query in Postgres?
2. Is it necessary to explicitly create a `TYPE` in advance?
   I know, that in MS SQL Server I have to define a table type to be able to declare a parameter of this type. Is it the same in Postgres?

We use Postgres version 11 that runs on AWS RDS, if that is important.

Comment: You said you see the queries in the log, but haven't described them as actually causing any kind of problem.  Maybe do nothing?

Comment: @jjanes, yes they do cause performance problem. It is faster to run a query once rather than 600 times.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid creating the type if it would only be used in a single place in the system.  You could avoid defining the type by using a VALUES list instead, but that doesn't work well with prepared statements because the list would need to be a fixed size at preparation.

Here is an example using a table I have handy with a VALUES list:

```
select * from pgbench_accounts 
join (values (5,''),(6,'foo')) t(aid, filler) 
on pgbench_accounts.aid=t.aid and pgbench_accounts.filler=t.filler;
```

You can type-cast the values of the first tuple in the list if you need to define the types.

Comment: If I use `VALUES`, it means that I need to build the text of the query in the application, right? I don't want to deal with escaping text values and concatenating them into the SQL. I want to pass values as parameter(s). Both to avoid SQL injection and for performance. I don't want to pass values as individual parameters. There will be thousands of them. I want to have a single parameter - a table / array.

I'm not familiar with Postgres and wanted to confirm whether it is really necessary to create a `TYPE` in advance to pass an array as a parameter.

Comment: I am also not a big fan of creating an object in the database that will be used only for one specific query. In this case this `TYPE` can be used only for this query. It is very specific. That's why I'm asking this question. Maybe there is some syntax in Postgres that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Python has psycopg2.extras.execute_values to assemble the text of the VALUES part of the query for you.  I don't know if other drivers have similar features.  But all reputable drivers should at least provide an method for quoting and escaping.